# jQuery to check empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var id = "<?php echo $val->id; ?>";

var myRadio = $('input[name=<?php echo "mala".$val->id; ?>]').val();

if (myRadio.val.length > 0){
   $("#anketa").load('http://www.svastara.rs/anketa/anketa_m1_data', 
       { answer: myRadio, id: id });
   }
});
```

Why this  `if (myRadio.val.length > 0)`  returns it looks like false, when i am sure that there is something in the string. If its not a good way, how to check that the string is empty or not?

Comment: It shouldn't "look false", it should (probably) throw an error. Why are you trying to take `val` of `val()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need in `val`, since you should already get the value with `val()` method in the previous line:

```
if (myRadio.length > 0) { ... }
```

Comment: still load the link, when i click on button and do not choose radio button

Answer (score 0):

```
if(myRadio)
return true;
else
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use myRadio.val.length due to myRadio is already the value of that input. So all you need is to check this variable with length.

```
var id = "<?php echo $val->id; ?>";
var myRadio = $('input[name=<?php echo "mala".$val->id; ?>]').val();
if (myRadio.length > 0){
     $("#anketa").load('http://www.svastara.rs/anketa/anketa_m1_data', { answer: myRadio, id: id });
}
```

You can have a better explanation at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp

Good luck!

Comment: I do not know why but it always give a true